# Passing list of models from one page to controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried to pass a list of models to controller but with no luck. I have a problem with generating empty view and then pass values from filled forms to controller. What I have:

**Models**

```
public class PostsModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class PostModel 
{
    public string Language {get;set;}
    public string X {get;set;}
    public string Y {get;set;}
    // and other properties
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult New()
{
    ViewData["ButtonName"] = "Add";

    return View(new PostsModel { PublishDate = DateTime.UtcNow });
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> New(PostsModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // some code
        // never reaches this point
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post">
    <h4>XYZ</h4>
    <hr />
    @{
        Model.Posts = new List<PostModel>(2);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Model.Posts.Add(new PostModel());
        }

        foreach (var test in Model.Posts)
        {
            <h4>xyz</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@test.Subject">Temat</label>
                <input asp-for="@test.Subject" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@test.Subject" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        }
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@ViewData["ButtonName"]</button>
</form>
```

Of course model is never valid. I don't have an idea how to do such functionality.

Comment: Is `PostsModel model` null when it gets passed in?

Comment: @chakeda: PostsModel is ok but list of PostModel is indeed null

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for collections - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) (and you populate the model in the controller code,  not in the view code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you have a right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StephenMuecke said, using for-loop is working approach. In this particular problem that I had it's enough to do:

**Controller:**

```
    public IActionResult New()
    {
        ViewData["ButtonName"] = "Add";

        // example:
        return View(new PostsModel { PublishDate = DateTime.UtcNow, Posts = new List<PostModel>(2) { new PostModel(), new PostModel() } });
    }
```

**View:**

```
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Posts.Count; i++)
        {
            <h4>xyz</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Posts[i].Subject">Temat</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Posts[i].Subject" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Posts[i].Subject" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*and so one*@
        }
```

I also want to thank M. Kostrzewski and M. Kaletka who also helped me on some .net group